# Using PHP to upload file and add the path to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Upload.php:

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "pics";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$Filename=$_POST['Filename'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
$pic=($_FILES['Filename']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("altabotanikk") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO picture (Filename,Description)
VALUES ('$Filename', '$Description')") ;

//Writes the Filename to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    //Tells you if its all ok
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['Filename']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
} else {
    //Gives and error if its not
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

And here is the form(in a separate file):

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Photo:</p>
    <input type="file" name="Filename"> 
    <p>Description</p>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="Description"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

The errors are

```
 Undefined index: Filename on Line 17
```

(the     $Filename=$_POST['Filename'];)

and

```
Undefined index: uploadedfile on Line 35
```

(the echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['Filename']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";)

```
echo"<pre>".print_r($_FILES,true)."</pre>";
```

gives me:

```
Array
(
    [Filename] => Array
        (
            [name] => Laserkanon.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\WampServer\tmp\php11D4.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 41813
        )

)
```

Comment: $_POST['Filename'] does not exist. $_FILES['uploadedfile'] does not exist. $_FILES['Filename'] exists. You may want to echo the value of $_FILES to see the array structure: `echo"<pre>".print_r($_FILES,true)."</pre>";`

Comment: If I had ANY idea whatsoever you actually meant there... where does that snippet go?
And thanks, lopez.mikhael

Comment: in upload.php you should use $_FILES to get file info instead $_POST['filename']. if you want to name this file from the form you should put input type=text name="filename...

Comment: You should re order the idea, first move the file into the directory, second save it on the Database.

Comment: Yupp, got rid of the first error... Still so much to learn...

Comment: Nurdglaw, I do not have any idea whatsoever on how to fix any errors... The errors are not supposed to be there...

Comment: use print_r($_FILES) in your upload.php to see what it contents

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta what?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: The errors indicate that variables you're trying to access are undefined. `$_POST['filename']` does not appear in your form. `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` does not appear in your form. Since you have not defined them, they are undefined.

Comment: @TheLastMelody yes because think this:
You save the file and then you move it but if the move fails for any reason? On your DB you have the row BUT the files is not there!

Comment: @showdev well, how do I define them?

Comment: @bksi thanks, updated post with result, but it tells me error is = or less than 0...

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta Yes, so, if I swap the places of the INSERT INTO and the (move_uploaded), it would be better?

Comment: @TheLastMelody at least you don't have the problem of "ghost files" in your DB.

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta And I hope I never will, but knowing myself, I will get there too...

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are old and will soon be removed from PHP entirely.  Update your code to use PDO or mysqli so that it will continue to work in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should use `print_r($_FILES)` to debug, and see what it contains. :

your `uploads.php` would look like:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "pics/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$Filename=basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
$Description=$_POST['Description'];


//Writes the Filename to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    //Tells you if its all ok
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
    // Connects to your Database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
    mysql_select_db("altabotanikk") or die(mysql_error()) ;

    //Writes the information to the database
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO picture (Filename,Description)
    VALUES ('$Filename', '$Description')") ;
} else {
    //Gives and error if its not
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}



?>
```

**EDIT:** Since this is old post, currently it is strongly recommended to use either [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead mysql_ functions in php

Comment: Nono, not trying to rename the file, I am trying to upload the file and a description, with it's original filename

Comment: According to your $_FILES array, the original filename is stored in $_FILES['Filename']['name'].

Comment: @bksi Yeah I do, now I have 5 errors instead of one :/ Undefined index srcFile and 
    `move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

+
  `move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'C:\WampServer\tmp\php7068.tmp' to 'pics'`

Comment: Yeah my mistake, someone tried to edit my post and returned it with one version. Try with this one. In your form use <input type="file" name="Filename"/>

Comment: You can;t have undefined index srcFile due i removed it from the code

Comment: @bksi Almost working now! It appeared in the database with the filename "Array" wich obviously is not the jpg file I uploaded ^_^"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31880/discussion-between-the-last-melody-and-bksi)

Comment: The question is what happens in the pics folder?

Comment: The file appears with it's filename unedited. So an improvement by far, but due to it not being in the database I can't display it :/

Answer (score -3):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("altabotanikk") or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

These are deprecated use the following..

```
 // Connects to your Database
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");
```

and to insert data use the following

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO  Table-Name (Column-Name)
VALUES ('$filename')" ;
```

Comment: Answering a 5 year old question with accepted answer to say the code is deprecated is not very useful.