# rename and store file in directory when duplicate filename found

Tags: php

i want to upload image with numerics at end of the file name or something unique, if duplicate file name found in directory. like if i upload imag.jpg it should be some uniqueid+imag.php . i researched multiple resources but now almost confused.
this is default reference code from w3schools. as i am new and learn from there and by practise, so,any help it will be thank you.

```
    if($_POST){

$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $pptimg =  $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use uniqid() php function to do this.

`$target_file = $target_dir . uniqid() . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: Thank Buddy! it is working, remaned file saved to directory. but how to save the path to database. currentlly i am storing this variable $pptimg =  $_FILES["file"]["name"]; to database. what should i change here to store new image to db.

Comment: Its Working Perfectly. got it and was able to update it to db.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with a time stamp that includes seconds.

The chances of another file having the same file name will be low.

Comment: I am unsure as to what you want to do exactly. Are you uploading it to a folder or a website ? Are you generating these images your self ? Depending on the job you want done there could be multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: i am uploading this to a folder on server and saving its path to database using form input. so can preview it later on.

Comment: Cool, May I ask how the image files are generated and is there any particular reason for your method ? Would be worth looking at other options also :) . I might have some alternative ideas. Although Gonzalo De-Spirito might have you covered :)

Comment: @nerdiere : i am not getting the sentence, how the image files are generated. 

well, i have created 3 step form and a preview page where we get all the submitted data and image for confirmation. on 3rd page of form we are taking image input and after submit it will go to a php page where this phpupload code is written, after processing and saving its path to db it will redirect to preview.php page.

Comment: @nerdiere : well buddy ! i followed Gonzalo De-Spirito answer and it worked and files getting save into directory but how i will save this new image path to DB, it is storing the default name of file, 
 as i am using variable $pptimg =  $_FILES["file"]["name"];  what should i do here.

Comment: I found this , you will need to connect to the database and make a query. You may want to rewrite this to suite your needs.                                                                                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153624/using-php-to-upload-file-and-add-the-path-to-mysql-database .

Comment: thanxx ! got it.